# Why does 'make' recompile several files when I change one file?

Tags: c++, makefile

When I edit one source file, does running make recompile that file plus all files for which that one is a dependency? If so, why?

Comment: Please post a [minimal sample](http://sscce.org/). It's impossible to answer questions without seeing what you're asking about.

Comment: I would argue that anyone with a good understanding of the make utility would find it possible to answer.

Comment: The point of providing sample code is to clarify and specify precisely what you're talking about. Technology is a subtle thing; small differences can have huge consequences. Without a representative sample, answerers can only guess at what's going on in your specific makefile. You may not be structuring things optimally. Why are you adverse to [improving your question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why?**
Because that is the whole purpose of having an Make file.
If a particular source file is modified then all dependant files should be recompiled with the modified file so that all of the dependant files refer the same source and the entire code base is in sync.

**How?**
`make` utility checks timestamps to check which files were modified.When an make file is created One needs to specify **dependency rules** which explicitly tell the utility which other files are dependant on particular file. So using these rules Make compiles all dependent files as well, So that the binaries generated refer the same updated code.

Comment: Ok for the why part, humor my example. File A contains a call to a function defined in file B. So if I just add a semicolon to file B, make must recompile A because for all make knows, the function signature called by A may have changed?

Comment: @bbarre: maybe. If B.h is a header file that *declares* or *defines* the function, and A.cpp includes B.h, then yes B.h should be a dependency of A.o (or A, or A.exe, whatever you build from A). But if B.cpp is a file that *defines* the function, whereas A.cpp gets its declaration of the function elsewhere, then provided you compile A.cpp and B.cpp separately to A.o and B.o, then B.cpp need not be a dependency of A.o. In that case both A.o and B.o are still dependencies of whatever executable you build from them. So if you change B.cpp leaving B.h alone, B.o and the exe are rebuilt, A.o isn't.

Answer (score 4):

If that file is #included in other files, it's reasonable to expect those other files to recompile as well as you don't want to have a "half" of your program new and the other "half" old.

Answer (score 0):

> When I edit one source file, does running make recompile that file
>   plus all files for which that one is a dependency? If so, why?

It can happen for a bad makefile (you haven't posted how it looks like).

Or the source file contains the implementation of a template, and is included somewhere.